# In C++11, how can I call new and reserve enough memory for the object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I have a class that is described that way :

```
class Foo {
    int size;
    int data[0];

public:
    Foo(int _size, int* _data) : size(_size) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            data[i] = adapt(_data[i]);
        }
    }

    // Other, uninteresting methods
}
```

I cannot change the design of that class.

How can I create an instance of that class ? Before calling the constructor, I have to make it reserve enough memory to store its data, so it has to be on the heap, not on the stack. I guess I want something like

```
Foo* place = static_cast<Foo*>(malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) * size));
*place = new Foo(size, data);  // I mean : "use the memory allocated in place to do your stuff !"
```

But I can't find a way to make it work.

EDIT : as commentators have noticed, this is not a very good overall design (with non-standards tricks such as `data[0]`), alas this is a library I am forced to use...

Comment: Placement `new` with manual allocation might help.

Comment: `int data[0]` isn't valid C++.

Comment: Placement new syntax: `new (address) Type(arguments...);` where `address` is `void*`. Anything created with placement `new` must be destroyed with an explicit destructor call; I somehow doubt that you want to do that manually so you'll best write a wrapper around `Foo` that deals with proper allocation/deallocation.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `std::vector`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry to nitpick, but no, that's valid C++; when the size is 0 it'll still return a valid pointer, but dereferencing it is undefined. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory

Comment: @legends2k: That has nothing to do with my comment.

Comment: @Philipp, actually the methods I've hidden do a lot of useful things so I can't use a `vector` instead. The library I'm supposed to use does a lot of micro-optimizations tricks, that's one of them.

Comment: The draft standard I have has a section [dcl.array] where it clearly states about arrays "If the constant-expression (5.19) is present,
it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero."

Comment: That's indeed not valid C++, but it's supported by some compilers such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: Relevant to the "Is is valid?" discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412749/are-flexible-array-members-valid-in-c

Comment: @KerrekSB: My bad, confused dynamic alloc. with automatic storage :( Just checked the spec. `If the constant-expression is present,
it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.`; With `-pedantic` g++ flags `warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could `malloc` the memory for the object and then use a [`placement new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) to create the object in the previously allocated memory :

```
void* memory = malloc(sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(int) * size);
Foo* foo = new (memory) Foo(size, data);
```

Note that in order to destroy this object, you can't use `delete`. You would have to manually call the destructor and then use `free` on the memory allocated with `malloc` :

```
foo->~Foo();
free(memory); //or free(foo);
```

Also note that, as *@Nikos C.* and *@GManNickG* suggested, you can do the same in a more *C++ way* using [`::operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) :

```
void* memory = ::operator new(sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(int) * size);
Foo* foo = new (memory) Foo(size, data);
...
foo->~Foo();
::operator delete(memory); //or ::operator delete(foo);
```

Comment: Would be slightly safer to do `malloc(sizeof(Foo) + ...` rather than `sizeof(int)`.  Just in case `Foo` gets another member in future.

Comment: You can actually avoid malloc() and do `void* memory = new char[sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(int) * size];`

Comment: `(void*)foo == memory` is guaranteed, and it is a good thing, or else you wouldn't have allocated enough memory.

Comment: @BenVoigt I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` or `new char[]` if you want raw memory, just use `::operator new`. Its only purpose in life is to allocate raw memory.

Comment: @GManNickG That's indeed the correct C++ way of doing it, but is there any practical difference between `::operator new` and `malloc` ?

Comment: @zakinster: You can replace the definition of `::operator new` with a custom memory manager. By using `malloc`, you bypass that.

Comment: After using `::operator new` and placement `new`, wouldn't it be valid to just `delete foo;`?

Comment: @aschepler: No, you can only `delete` what you `new`'d. While it may share the lexical word "new", they are different things. To undo `::operator new`, you `::operator delete`.

Comment: But you did `new` the `Foo` object, in the expression `new (memory) Foo(size+data)`.  (Though it should be `::delete foo;`, not just `delete foo;`.)

Comment: @aschepler: That's not `new`ing a `Foo`, that's `new (memory)`ing a `Foo`. :) There is no `delete (memory)` in the language to match which is where the asymmetry kicks in (missing delete).

Comment: Are there no alignment issues with that kind of things?

Answer (score 8):

You have a library that does this thing but doesn't supply a factory function? For shame!

Anyway, while zakinster's method is right (I'd directly call operator new instead of newing an array of chars, though), it's also error-prone, so you should wrap it up.

```
struct raw_delete {
  void operator ()(void* ptr) {
    ::operator delete(ptr);
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct destroy_and_delete {
  void operator ()(T* ptr) {
    if (ptr) {
      ptr->~T();
      ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
  }
};
template <typename T>
using dd_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, destroy_and_delete<T>>;

using FooUniquePtr = dd_unique_ptr<Foo>;

FooUniquePtr CreateFoo(int* data, int size) {
  std::unique_ptr<void, raw_delete> memory{
    ::operator new(sizeof(Foo) + size * sizeof(int))
  };
  Foo* result = new (memory.get()) Foo(size, data);
  memory.release();
  return FooUniquePtr{result};
}
```

Yes, there's a bit of overhead here, but most of this stuff is reusable.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be lazy simply use a `std::vector<Foo>`. It will use more space (I think 3 pointers instead of 1) but you get all the benefits of a container and really no downsides if you know it is never going to change in size.

Your objects will be movable given your definition so you can safely do the following to eliminate reallocation of the vector during initial fill...

```
auto initialFooValue = Foo(0, 0)
auto fooContainer = std::vector<Foo>(size, initialFooValue);

int i = 0;
for (auto& moveFoo : whereverYouAreFillingFrom)
{
    fooContainer[i] = std::move(moveFoo);
    ++i;
}
```

Since std::vector is contiguous you can also just memcopy into it safely since your objects are [trivially-copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

Comment: That's a solution I thought of, but alas I'm forced to use to provided library for performance reasons...

Comment: `std::vector`'s own content is contiguous within itself, but it is not contiguous with the larger structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think a *good* C++ solution is to get raw memory with new and then use placement new to embed your class into it.

getting raw memory works like this:

```
Foo *f = static_cast<Foo *>(operator new(sizeof(Foo));
```

constructing the object in received memory works like this:

```
new (f) Foo(size, data); // placement new
```

remember that this also means that you have to **manually** clean up the place.

```
f->~Foo(); // call the destructor
operator delete(f); // free the memory again
```

My personal opinion is, that it is bad to use `malloc` and `free` in newly written C++ code.