# Standard way of overlay flexible array member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

So the server sends the data just as packed structures, so what only need to decode is to overlay the structure pointer on the buffer. However one of the structure is a dynamic array kind of data, but I learned that flexible array member is not a C++ standard feature. How can I do it in standard C++ way, but without copying like a `vector`?

```
// on wire format: | field a | length | length of struct b |
// the sturcts are defined packed
__pragma(pack(1))
struct B {
    //...
};
struct Msg {
    int32_t a;
    uint32_t length;
    B *data; // how to declare this?
};
__pragma(pack())
char *buf = readIO();
// overlay, without copy and assignments of each field
const Msg *m = reinterpret_cast<const Msg *>(buf);
// access m->data[i] from 0 to length
```

Comment: Write accessors. You have so many operators to choose from. Does the data come with padding between members? Is it _guaranteed_ that the padding between members is the same as the C++ compiler chooses to do? Is it guaranteed that `field a` will have __at least__ 16 bits and the same count of bits that C++ compiler chooses for `int`? Same for `size_t`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way of interop'ing with C flexible array members from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839009/what-is-the-correct-way-of-interoping-with-c-flexible-array-members-from-c)

Comment: For something like this, you will require proper deserialization. Otherwise, there is no way for your program to know the actual size of `data`.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium by reading the first 2 members you already know the size of data without deserialization

Comment: if compiler extensions are allowed then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894135/995714).

Comment: Is the buffer `buf` returned by `readIO` _guaranteed_ to be properly aligned to `alignof(Msg)`? Are data guaranteed to have the same endianess as your program is using? In short, you can't just simply alias data.

Comment: yes, the structure are actually packed, i just updated code. endianess is handled but just skipped to focus on the variable length data field problem. i wanna avoid copying that's the main issue.

Comment: Can't you just write `the_type& operator[](size_t idx) { return *reinterpret_cast<the_type*>(msg + offset); }`? It seems off that you would _want_ to alias the data - write accessors. `int16_t& a() { return *reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(buf); }` `uint64_t& length() { return *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(buf + sizeof(int16_t)); }` etc.. but still - alignment. And still, data sizes.

Comment: all the structures are POD, since they match wire format. i try to avoid adding methods into the strucutres.

Comment: sorry all the fields are fixed size data types, just updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // on wire format: | field a | length | length of struct b |
> ```

You can't overlay the struct, because you can't guarantee that the binary representation of `Msg` will match the on wire format. Also `int` is **at least** 16 bits, can be any number of bits greater than 16, and `size_t` has various size depending on architecture.

Write actual accessors to the data. Use fixed width integer types. It will only work if the data actually point to a properly aligned region. This method allows you to write assertions and `throw` exceptions when stuff goes bad (for example, you can throw on out-of-bounds access to the array).

```
struct Msg {
    constexpr static size_t your_required_alignment = alingof(uint32_t);
    char *buf;
    Msg (char *buf) : buf(buf) {
        assert((uintptr_t)buf % your_required_alignment == 0);
    }
    int32_t& get_a() { return *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(buf); }
    uint32_t& length() { return *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(buf + sizeof(int32_t)); }
    struct Barray {
       char *buf;
       Barray(char *buf) : buf(buf) {}
       int16_t &operator[](size_t idx) {
           return *reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(buf + idx * sizeof(int16_t));
       }
    }
    Barray data() {
        return buf + sizeof(int32_t) + sizoef(uint32_t);
    }
};


int main() {
   Msg msg(readIO());
   std::cout << msg.a() << msg.length();
   msg.data()[1] = 5;
   // or maybe even implement straight operator[]:
   // msg[1] = 5;
}
```

If the data do not point to a properly aligned region, you *have to* copy the data, there is no possibility to access them using other types then `char`.

Answer (score 1):

A standard solution is to not represent the array as a member of the message, but rather as a separate object.

```
struct Msg {
    int a;
    size_t length;
};

const Msg& m = *reinterpret_cast<const Msg*>(buf);
span<const B> data = {
    reinterpret_cast<const B*>(buf + sizeof(Msg)),
    m.length,
};
```

Note that reinterpretation / copying of bytes is not portable between systems with different representations (byte endianness, integer sizes, alignments, subobject packing etc.), and same representation is typically not something that can be assumed in network communication.

Comment: `span` is C++20, the question has the C++17 tag.

Comment: @Enlico Thanks for pointing out. The answer is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to do this in C was to declare data as an array of length one as the last struct member. You then allocate the space needed as if the array was larger.
Seems to work fine in C++ as well. You should perhaps wrap access to the data in a span or equivalent, so the implementation details don't leak outside your class.

```
#include <string>
#include <span>

struct B {
    float x;
    float y;
};
struct Msg {
    int a;
    std::size_t length;
    B data[1];
};

char* readIO()
{
    constexpr int numData = 3;
    char* out = new char[sizeof(Msg) + sizeof(B) * (numData - 1)]; 
    return out;
}
int main(){
    char *buf = readIO();
    // overlay, without copy and assignments of each field
    const Msg *m = reinterpret_cast<const Msg *>(buf);
    // access m->data[i] from 0 to length
    std::span<const B> data(m->data, m->length);
    for(auto& b: data)
    {
        // do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EoMbeE8or

Comment: the result of `new char[...]` will not be correctly aligned with an object of type `struct Msg`, will it?

Comment: @StephanLechner It will be correctly aligned.

Comment: The new here is only for the example, it seems the OP knows the data will be aligned (and of proper endiannes etc), and just needs to know how this pattern works syntactically.

Comment: @eerorika: OK, just saw the pack(1)

Comment: @StephanLechner It doesn't matter. Global allocator is guaranteed to align to at least the maximum natural alignment, and `Msg` isn't overaligned.